# Error message saying debug assertion failed

Tags: c

I've been trying to make a save function that saves a new file with a different file name and i get this error message that complains about the fread and i guess its becuase its not finding the fopen but it is written and I still get an error message so if anyone would help to show in code whats wrong I would be thankful.

code link:

Expression: stream != nullptr
Line: 48

I´m not sure why the error appears in the choice menu when I want to save a new file but dont show up when the user picks anything else of the menu choices.

Example:

Input:

Comment: You should include a minimal complete example program in your post.

Comment: Well, apparently some pointer is null when it shouldn't be. Given that you don't check whether the files in the `save()` function could be opened properly, the file pointers look like prime suspects. (Also, don't use `feof` as a condition to break the loop. Check the return value of `fread` instead.)

Comment: "Debug assertion failed" message is shown only in debug version. In release all `assert`-s are compiled as nothing / skipped.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  And, in future, include the relevant code in the question.  If it is part of a bigger program, you can include a link to the bigger program, but the question should be answerable by looking at the question, not requiring us to go offsite to find the code to be studied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*fflush(stdin);* probably does not work after `printf("\nEnter the New File Name:");` so the `scanf("%[^\n]", name);` has a '\n' in input and does nothing and *name* is not set and is empty, after

```
    fp = fopen(name, "wb");
    fp1 = fopen(fname, "rb");
```

because name is non valid the fopen doesn't work so after *fp* and *fp1* are null, which produces the assertion fail.

Do not use *fflush*, and after your *fopen* check all the time you don't get a null pointer.

Just replace

```
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]", name);
```

by

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

and all will be ok

Comment: Have tried that @bruno and it does not change the fact that the same error appears

Comment: "*scanf("%[^\n]", name); must be scanf("%[^\n]", &name);*" Huh? Why?

Comment: @RudolfHakkenien I go back my first answer, the problem is the _fflush_ for me, if I replace it by a _getchar()_ to read the '\n 'after the read of 'Y' all works

Comment: @bruno are you not getting an error message after the new file name is selected?

Comment: @RudolfHakkenien no and the file is saved using the name I enter

Comment: @RudolfHakkenien your program does actions depending in the inputs, if you do not give the sequence of inputs we can just try with our own inputs, so may be you have a problem when I don't have because we do not use the same sequences of inputs/actions

Comment: @RudolfHakkenien btw just replace `fflush(stdin); scanf("%[^\n]", name);` by `scanf("%s", name);` and all will be ok

Comment: @bruno yeah that make since why we get different results, do you chose the new file name as a .dat or something else? maybe thats why I get an error message even after changing like you suggested

Comment: @RudolfHakkenien I use a new filename

Comment: @RudolfHakkenien for instance I do : 1<enter> a<enter> 2<enter> 3<enter> f<enter> p<enter> e<enter> <enter> 6<enter> Y<enter> foo<enter> <enter> 7<enter>